# If I use ViewBinding in Fragments, would I have a NPE after onDestoryView()?

Tags: android

I am trying to use ViewBinding in Fragments.

First, Google said as below :

> Note: Fragments outlive their views. Make sure you clean up any references to the binding class instance in the fragment's onDestroyView() method. [[Use view binding in fragments](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding#fragments)]

So, I have wrote the code as below :

```
private var _binding: ResultProfileBinding? = null
// This property is only valid between onCreateView and
// onDestroyView.
private val binding get() = _binding!!

override fun onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView()
    _binding = null
}
```

Then, I got a concern about NPE after onDestoryView().

It is safe? Suppose you received a network response at some point between onDestoryView() and onDetact()

Comment: Can't we do this `binding.lifecycleOwner = viewLifecycleOwner` instead?

Comment: Sure, we can resolve as deal with lifecycle. but, I wanted to use it without adding extra logic. so I had wrote this question. Thank you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Fragments outlive their views

Let's explain it, assume you have Fragment A and B (both A and B in BackStack) same container view and same FragmentManager. When you replace fragment A by B. All view elements of A will be destroyed but the instance of Fragment A still alive in fragment `BackStack`. It means if you keep value of `_binding` it can be leaks because it still keep view reference but Android System wants to clear it. So Google recommends you assign null to `_binding` to release view reference.

> Suppose you received a network response at some point between onDestoryView() and onDetact()

You shouldn't handle any network response after onDestroyView if it update your UI because your fragment views not present to User.

Comment: Eventually I have to check the lifecycle of the Fragment before processing the response. right? then, I need to logic for avoid NPE. If possible, I wanted to use it without adding extra logic. so I had wrote this question. Thank you.

Comment: I recommend you still assign binding to null and keep track lifecycle before processing the response.