# Why in Android binding examples Google uses val binding and var _binding?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding

The example is [the following](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding#fragments):

```
private var _binding: ResultProfileBinding? = null
// This property is only valid between onCreateView and
// onDestroyView.
private val binding get() = _binding!!

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    _binding = ResultProfileBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
    val view = binding.root
    return view
}

override fun onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView()
    _binding = null
}
```

Why using a `var _binding` and a `val binding`, which simply gets `_binding`, and not using a `lateinit var binding` only? Is there something behind this choice?

Indeed, in the [activity's example](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding#activities), they actually use a `lateinit var`:

```
private lateinit var binding: ResultProfileBinding

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ResultProfileBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    val view = binding.root
    setContentView(view)
}
```

Why uselessly complicating that code?

Comment: The first example provided is manually doing the same as the second example, just in a less pragmatic way.  Anywhere you're writing `!!` and referencing kotlin syntax it's probably a code smell, for me it's only use should be when calling members/variables from in Kotlin from Java code, and nothing around variable initialisation.

Comment: May it be linked to the impossibility to set the binding to null if using a `lateinit var`? Maybe for avoiding possible leaks?

Comment: Having looked at the example this is the case here : Note: Fragments outlive their views. Make sure you clean up any references to the binding class instance in the fragment's.  However null safety is lost in doing it this way.  It would only ever be a short term leak as the reference is changed every time `onCreateView` is called.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62039407/1507512) seems to be the answer to the question (also explaining why fragments and activities manage their binding differently)

Answer (score 1):

It's naming convention where if you have private Kotlin properties then you should start it with an underscore.

Kotlin Docs:

> **Names for backing properties :**
> *If a class has two properties which are conceptually the same but one is part of a public API and another is an implementation detail, use an underscore as the prefix for the name of the private property:*

```
class C {
    private val _elementList = mutableListOf<Element>()

    val elementList: List<Element>
         get() = _elementList
}
```

Comment: My problem is not the underscore (both `_binding` and `binding` are private), but the real need to have two variables rather than a single `lateinit var`

Comment: i guess second one is val so can't be changed so they have assigned the _binding as a backing property which can be changed, but again someone more experience can comment a more satisfactory explanation.

Comment: @Massimo `_binding` is `var`; mutable (non-const). `_binding` is `val`; immutable (const). `_binding` is only valid between `onCreate` and `onDestroy`, and so must be the unsafe nullable type as it is in the example you provided (hence, `var` and `?`) , and what `binding` provides is an immutable (safe non-nullable) reference to the root of an inflated layout, which is returned as the view. `lateinit` wouldn't work here to ref any of the views because it must be a `var` and as an unsafe nullable type would allow for a returned reference to be changed or null prior to referencing.

Answer (score 1):

In the example that you provide, both variables are indeed private, but the concept of backing properties doesn't exlusively provide a public accessor to a private variable or member.

When implementing backing properties, the importance of the implementation is that the backing property is mutable, or `var`. The public accessor is typically immutable, const, or `val`.

The backing property can be changed, and so often times in designing a class we make a property private and provide a public accessor in order to ensure that it cannot be modified by anything other than the class's own methods/logic.

In the example you provided, both properties are private. This however doesn't mean that a `lateinit var` implementation would suffice, because whether the property can be initialized at declaration isn't the only issue to deal with.

`_binding` is `var`; **mutable** *(non-const)*.
`_binding` is `val`; **immutable** *(const)*.

`_binding` is only valid between `onCreate` and `onDestroy`, and so must be the *unsafe nullable* type as it is in the example you provided (hence, `var` and `?`).

`binding` provides an **immutable** (*safe non-nullable*) reference to the root of an inflated layout, which is then returned as the view reference.

`lateinit var` wouldn't work here to reference *any* of the views because it must be a `var` and as an *unsafe nullable* type would allow for a returned reference to be changed or `null` prior to referencing; this wouldn't satisfy the requirements of the method.

In your later example you see that a `lateinit` compiles and works,but semantically I don't think that is actually appropriate;
For someone reading the code, using the first example provided, the circumstances are clear and a `NullPointerException` is guaranteed if the reference is null thanks to the ***unsafe nullable*** *type `(T?)` conversion to a* ***non-nullable*** *type `(T)`, `!!`*:

```kotlin
private var _binding: ResultProfileBinding? = null
// This property is only valid between onCreateView and
// onDestroyView.
private val binding get() = _binding!!
```